# Map over CompactBuffer in an rdd

Tags: scala, rdd, scala-2.10

I have an RDD which was groupByKey as below,

(1, CompactBuffer(2.0, 3.0, 4.0)), 
(2, CompactBuffer(1.0, -1.0, -2.0))

And I wish to mapValues into (1*x_1^2, 2*x_2^2, 3*x_3^2)

which should look like this,

(1, CompactBuffer(4.0, 18.0, 48.0)),
(2, CompactBuffer(1.0, 2.0, 12.0))

What should I do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I get the n'th elements in CompactBuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapValues` to process the CompactBuffer content using `zip` with a `Stream(1, 2, ...)`, like in the following:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 2.0),
  (1, 3.0),
  (1, 4.0),
  (2, 1.0),
  (2, -1.0),
  (2, -2.0)
))

val groupedRDD = rdd.groupByKey
// res1: Array[(Int, Iterable[Double])] = Array(
//   (1,CompactBuffer(2.0, 3.0, 4.0)), (2,CompactBuffer(1.0, -1.0, -2.0))
// )

groupedRDD.mapValues( l =>
  l.zip(Stream from 1).map{ case (v, i) => v * v * i }
)
// res2: Array[(Int, Iterable[Double])] = Array(
//   (1,List(4.0, 18.0, 48.0)), (2,List(1.0, 2.0, 12.0))
// )
```

Comment: I have a further question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949324/how-to-sum-a-part-of-a-list-in-rdd)