# How to Sum a part of a list in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, scala-2.10

I have an RDD, and I would like to sum a part of the list.

```
(key, element2 + element3)
(1, List(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)), (2, List(1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0))
```

output should look like this,

```
(1, 7.0), (2, -3.0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` and indexing on the second part:

```
yourRddOfTuples.map(tuple => {val list = tuple._2; list(1) + list(2)})
```

Update after your comment, convert it to `Vector`:

```
yourRddOfTuples.map(tuple => {val vs = tuple._2.toVector; vs(1) + vs(2)})
```

Or if you do not want to use conversions:

```
yourRddOfTuples.map(_._2.drop(1).take(2).sum)
```

This skips the first element (`.drop(1)`) from the second element of the tuple (`.map(_._2`), takes the next two (`.take(2)`) (might be less if you have less) and sums them (`.sum`).

Comment: There's an error "Iterable[Double] does not take parameters"

Comment: list(1) + list(2)

Comment: In that case I doubt you have a `List` in the second argument, but converting to `Vector` should fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the key-list pair to obtain the 2nd and 3rd list elements as follows:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, List(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)),
  (2, List(1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0))
))

rdd.map{ case (k, l) => (k, l(1) + l(2)) }.collect
// res1: Array[(Int, Double)] = Array((1,7.0), (2,-3.0))
```

Comment: There's an error "Iterable[Double] does not take parameters"

Comment: The list came from .zip(Stream ).map

Comment: @ken, if you have a collection of Iterable[Double] rather than a list as in your sample data, you can first do a `toList` to convert it to a list.